# Google API service object is not created when ran as exe

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

I've written a script to add events to Google calendar using the Google Calendar API for python. It works perfectly when ran as just a python script but after making it an exe with pyinstaller it fails to create a serivce object.

Code for creating service object:

```
def create_service(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, *scopes, prefix=''):
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = client_secret_file
    API_SERVICE_NAME = api_name
    API_VERSION = api_version
    SCOPES = [scope for scope in scopes[0]]
    
    cred = None
    working_dir = os.getcwd()
    token_dir = 'token files'
    pickle_file = f'token_{API_SERVICE_NAME}_{API_VERSION}{prefix}.pickle'

    ### Check if token dir exists first, if not, create the folder
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(working_dir, token_dir)):
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(working_dir, token_dir))

    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(working_dir, token_dir, pickle_file)):
        with open(os.path.join(working_dir, token_dir, pickle_file), 'rb') as token:
            cred = pickle.load(token)

    if not cred or not cred.valid:
        if cred and cred.expired and cred.refresh_token:
            cred.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
            cred = flow.run_local_server()

        with open(os.path.join(working_dir, token_dir, pickle_file), 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(cred, token)

    try:
        service = build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=cred)
        print(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, 'service created successfully')
        return service
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print(f'Failed to create service instance for {API_SERVICE_NAME}')
        os.remove(os.path.join(working_dir, token_dir, pickle_file))
        return None
```

And I create the service object using:

```
created_event = service.events().quickAdd(
            calendarId=Calendar_two,
            text=eventtext).execute()
```

When ran as a .py it works fine and I get the "serivce created successfully" print, but when ran as exe it fails and gives me the "failed to create service" print and spits out the following error: *"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'events"*.

Visual studio PyLint also spits out this error: *Instance of 'Resource' has no 'events' member [E:no-member]*. But again, it still works as a .py

[Here is the same code in a google example](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/quickAdd#python)

[This guy had the exact same problem a few months ago but didn't get any replies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72611678/google-api-service-object-is-not-created-when-i-make-exe-file)

Comment: What does it say before "failed to create service"? `print(e)` should print the error.

Comment: You shouldn't catch all the excpetions with `except Exceptions`. You should catch only the ones you know how to handle and let your script fail fast on everything else instead of returning `None` and then thinking why *'NoneType' object has no attribute 'events'*